# Is there a way to add all files and directories that are unversioned to SVN repository?

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

Is there a way to perform an `svn add` command that will add only unversioned files?

Currently if I try to do `svn add` on a direcotry that contains a mix of versioned and unversioned files I receive the `mydir/ is already under version control` message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're on a Linux/UNIX commandline:

```
svn status | grep '\?' | awk '{print $2;}' | xargs svn add
```

Comment: Just to be slightly more explicit: grep '^\?'

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! One wonders why svn does not support this natively though.

Comment: Camsoft, you can modify that line to do removes, moves, deletes, etc, just change out the ? mark and the svn add command to do a different function. For example, to remove all missing files: svn status | grep '^\!' | awk '{print $2;}' | xargs svn rm

Comment: Yup. If you're anything like me, you'll end up with a small collection of one-liner shell scripts for doing common batch svn stuff.

@Camsoft: One wonders why svn does not support a lot of things natively ;)

Comment: It works, but consider that the last part: "xargs svn add" will fail with "Not enough arguments provided" error if no unversioned file is found.

Answer (score 1):

Try svn add * --force
 to force it into the already version controlled directory.